# Code Column Read Only Issue in Master Data Services 2016

Tags: sql-server-2016, master-data-services

I have an issue in Master Data Services 2016 my Question is.

Our Client wants to see the Code Column in Excel but he is saying that he couldn't Insert or update the Code Value itself  in excel .  To fulfil his requirement I set the Code value automatically generated and Read Only. But when I set Code Column read Only then  MDS is not allowing us to insert new record .

Answer (score 0):

If a business user wants to insert and update codes, they can't be automatically generated. It's the same as an IDENTITY property in a SQL Server table.

If they have problems updating code values because they were already used, it's because code values are soft-deleted. In that case you need to purge them.

Pre-SQL Server 2016: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3646/purging-entity-members-in-sql-server-master-data-services/

SQL Server 2016 and later: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4588/purge-an-entity-in-master-data-services-2016/

Comment: Koen that's not a case, actually we don't want to give rights to user for editing and inserting the Code column value, in this case we have to set code column read only , but problems occurs here is we set code column read only  then we cannot insert new row via MDS, .

Comment: Well, users cannot edit or insert new code columns. However, if you set a column to read-only, it means new data can't be inserted, because that would be writing data into the column. How exactly did you set the column to read-only?

Comment: When i set the CODE or NAME column read only then MDS is not allowing to insert new record, if I set other than (Code and Name) column read  only then we can insert new record. I red an article where it is mentioned that "we shouldn’t define permission on Name and code as the permission shall not be enforced"  , below is the link                  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/master-data-services/leaf-permissions-master-data-services